# Facebook POST TO WALL . How to?

Tags: php, facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-wall

Hi guys I have big problem with  " POST TO WALL ". Can someone show me how to do that ?

```
<?php

 $app_id = "myappid";

 $canvas_page = "mycanvaspage";

 $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

 $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

 list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

 $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

 if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
  ?>
```

I know how to make a POST TO WALL with dialog window but can someone show me how to make it wihout it ?

Comment: what did you try? and what were your results?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Comment: Is it just me or I've seen this question multiple times in the last week...

Comment: how can i add a publish_stream premission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with facebook php lib , and publish stream permission :

```
try {
     $facebook -> api ('/' . $fbID . '/feed', 'POST', $post);
       #where $post is array like array('name' => 'test' , 'description' => 'test');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
     #if eny error
         #u can get it $e -> getMessage() 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Olegs Testors but can u tell me  how to get a this premissions